# Will there be a version of Juno based on Ubuntu 19.04 or 19.10 before 20.04 LTS?

Tags: release-juno

Is there a way to upgrade from the current Juno to a more advanced release of Ubuntu such as 19.04 or 19.10? Also, what is the reason to necessarily base on LTS releases and, as a consequence, will there be a new Elementary OS release based on 20.04LTS in first quarter 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elementary only bases itself off the LTS versions of Ubuntu to reduce the development workload in continually revalidating against newer library and base package versions. So yes, the next major elementary version will be based off the next LTS release.

It may be possible to attempt upgrades yourself, just in the same way as it may be possible to run the pantheon desktop environment on newer versions of Ubuntu or other distributions. But you'd be doing so with no expectation of support from the elementary developers.

However, there are often minor releases that come with updated kernels and drivers (based off the Ubuntu HWE stack) to keep up with newer hardware. For example, Loki had a 0.4.1 release that included this and Juno is expected to have a 5.1 release with the same.

Also, with Flatpak support coming in AppCenter, it ought to be possible to keep user facing applications more up to date easily. So an older base OS will matter less.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informations. Is there a way to improve eventually the ties between Ubuntu and ElementaryOS? It's an area that passionates me and I would like to contribute if that is ever a possibility, as I read it is an area where there is place for improvements. Is it required to be an expert at kernel level in order to be able to do so? 5.1: would there be any idea of a release date? Ok, understood the rest, thank you.